# Why is a protonated carboxylic acid less acidic than a protonated ester?

Tags: organic-chemistry, acid-base, carbonyl-compounds

To my understanding, both have analogous resonance structures except that the ester has on -OR and the carboxylic acid has an -OH. Why is a positive charge on C-O-R more stable than on C-O-H?

Comment: Nice question!  It could be improved a bit if you added the source you used for the acidity of protonated carboxylic acids and protonated esters.  Did you measure these yourself?  Are you talking about in solution or in the gas phase?   And what do you mean by "stable"? etc. etc.

Comment: Thank you. I mean in solution, why the pKa of a protonated carboxylic acid is higher than a protonated ester.

Comment: Meh, this example is nothing you could not try to brush off with inductive effect or somesuch. Why not ask about ketone instead of ester. Or about ether or alcohol? It appears this resonance stabilisation is at best useless in such stuff. This is simply way beyond lame high school rationalisations. [Evans table](https://organicchemistrydata.org/hansreich/resources/pka/pka_data/evans_pKa_table.pdf) puts protonated acid as strongest of all of them. These are more or less debatable values, though. All strong acids without a good way to find reliable data.

Comment: related https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/116449/what-atom-would-be-protonated-first-in-a-strongly-acidic-solution https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/30864/protonation-of-ketone-and-ester

Comment: @Mithoron Uncle Al is that you?